# Text to speech issue in API Level 22

Tags: java, android

I was trying to converting `text to speech` in API level 22. Unfortunately, it's not working below API level 23.

```
tts=new TextToSpeech(MainActivity.this, new TextToSpeech.OnInitListener() {
        @Override
        public void onInit(int status) {
            if (status!=TextToSpeech.ERROR)
            {
                tts.setLanguage(Locale.US);
            }
        }
    });


    btnSpeak.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String text=etxtText.getText().toString();

            tts.speak(text,TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH,null);
            //1.0f is default speech rate, increase to high and decrease to lower
            tts.setSpeechRate(1.0f);


        }
    });



}


@Override
protected void onPause() {

    if (tts!=null)
    {
        //to stop speech
        tts.stop();
        tts.shutdown();

    }
    super.onPause();
}
```

It's working in upper version. But, not in API level 22. Is there possible way to run it in API level 22.

Comment: TTS is a very very old API added on API level 4. Maybe you're trying to use a constant that or method that was defined on api lvl 23+. Take a look at the official documentation https://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/tts/TextToSpeech

Comment: @Leuofiridia Could you check my source code in [git](https://github.com/Istiakshovon/textToSpeech/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/example/speechtotext/MainActivity.java)
Don't look at `API level` cause, I changed it after i try on `API level 22`.
Even, I am not getting any error when I click on button.

Comment: @Leuofiridia I think I am having issue to set `language`. Cause, i set a Toast a on it. But, no Toast message are showing. So, Could you say what to do now?